# Umbraco Node Permissions

Tags: umbraco

I have searched for hours and not found the answer to this, so was hoping someone here could help.

How do I get the roles set on a node from code behind?

I have my node: `Node nodeToCheck = new Node(nodeID);`

How do I now know what role permissions are set on this node?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is using aspnet membership if it makes a difference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just found out how to do this, so thought I would report back here:

```
string[] roles = Access.GetAccessingMembershipRoles(int.Parse(nodeID), nodeToCheck.Path);
```

or simpler if you do not want to manually check the roles assigned you can check against the membershipuser

```
bool hasAccess = Access.HasAccess(int.Parse(nodeID), nodeToCheck.Path, MembershipHelper.GetCurrentUser());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Umbraco (after 4.7) we can simply do

```
node.HasAccess // this tells you if the current user has access to that node
```

Before that we had

```
node.HasAccess() // or something like that..
```